# Hadoop localhost:9870 don't work before format hdfs namenode

Tags: hadoop

I have installed the hadoop.

When I start dfs and yarn, just yarn localhost work. For dfs localhost work, I need to do "bin/hdfs namenode -format" every time I start my laptop, and then start dfs, and it works.

How can I fix this ?
Sorry my bad english

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You always have to format the namenode at first start.

If you are needing to do it more than once, you'll need to look at the logs to find out why HDFS is not starting... More than likely, you're just shutting down your computer, and not stopping HDFS process, and the file blocks are becoming corrupt

Comment: I use `sbin/stop-dfs.sh` and `sbin/stop-yarn.sh` before shut down my computer. Where can I find the logs ?

Comment: Depends how you installed Hadoop. By default, there should be a logs directory next to sbin

Comment: My namenode was saving in a temporary system folder, this is why I have to format namenoda every pc restart. Thank you for the attention!!!!

Comment: Formatting the namenode solves the problem!